# Changing whole line in file

Tags: python, list, file

My program must take one line in file by first parameter (312, 621) and change in line one or both parameters. After that must write in file again. *first parameter is unique and not changeable*

*File before anything:*

```
312|fotelja snesko|white
621|digimon tabure|black
```

**My code right now:**

```
key = input("key >>")

entitet = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r+")
allDATA = entitet.readlines()
entitet.close()
for line in allDATA:
    lineLST = line.split("|")

    while key == lineLST[0]:

        print("name", lineLST[1])
        name = input("name >> ")
        if name == "":
            name = lineLST[1]

        print("color", lineLST[2])
        color = input("color >> ")
        if color == "":
            color = lineLST[2]
```

key input: 312

name input: cokoloko

color input: blue

*File after:*

```
312|cokoloko|blue
621|digimon tabure|black
```

**Question:** *How i can rewrite new input with previously line, without losing line two.*

Answer (score 1):

try looking at the fileinput module

```
for line in fileinput.input("input_file.txt"):
    if check(line):
       print line.replace("red","blue")
    else:
       print line
```

Comment: This cannot help me , i must change whole line without losing previously or after line